# sich verbunden sein

Tags: verb, meaning-in-context, reflexive

I have come across the sentence

```
Sie waren sich eng verbunden.
```

where the word *verbinden* is used in combination with *sich*. The sentence describes a relation between two brothers.

I know the most common meaning of *verbinden* is *to connect*. What is the role of *sich* in this context, and how would dropping it change the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the two most common versions of this phrase:

> Sie waren eng verbunden.
> <sup>They were closely connected.</sup>

> Sie waren miteinander eng verbunden. = Sie waren eng miteinander verbunden.
> <sup>They were closely connected with each other.</sup>

The version where *miteinander* is replaced by the reflexive pronoun *sich* is much rarer used, but it is used. (I found some books where this phrase appears.) But while *miteinander* is more often placed behind *eng* (both versions are ok) the word *sich* must stand before *eng.*

The meaning of *»Sie waren sich eng verbunden.«* is somewhere in between the meaning of the two sentences above, wich already mean almost the same.

So, it's just a stylistic variation. I wouldn't use it, because to me it sounds a little bit strange, but again: It's a matter of style which can be the subject of long but pointless discussions.

Answer (score 3):

In this sentence, *sich* is a dative reflexive pronoun.

One can tell it's dative because only dative makes sense in connection with *verbunden sein*: *jemandem[Dat] verbunden sein.*

Normally it would mean *to him/herself*. In this context, however, it means *to each other*. A less ambiguous word for *each other* is *einander*.

So the literal meaning is:

> They were connected to each other.

where *sich* translates to *to each other*.

The actual meaning, however, is rather something along the lines of "They had a [close] relationship".

Comment: You could add that _sich_ tends to replace the "proper" correlative pronoun _einander_, which would be prescriptively appropriate here.

Comment: I added a mention of *einander*.

Answer (score 0):

This phrase means "They were close with each other"

Sich means "each other" in this case but also means "with himself/herself"

You can also say "einander" which is a bit more formal - "sie waren miteinander eng verbunden"

Answer (score 0):

*sich* in this phrase means "to each other":

*Sie waren eng verbunden* (without *sich*) means "they were closely connected", but not necessarily to each other. For example, each individual item could be closely connected to some other item: *Die Blüten sind eng mit dem Stil verbunden.* "The blossoms are closely connected to the stems." With *sich* the objects are closely connected **to each other**.

Thus, *sie waren sich eng verbunden* means "they were closely connected to each other" or, more freely, "they were fast friends".

The phrase *sich verbunden sein* is near obsolete today and only used by writers who attempt to emulate a "classical", Goethe era style. I believe the phrase is not understood by many native speakers of German today.